# How to know if TCF agent is running ot not in my ZYNQ board?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux

I have booted linux into my ZYNQ 7000 (AVNET) board through Jtag, tftpboot. Next, made it boot from QSPI. The TCF agent was enabled in my Petalinux configuration. Now I am trying to run a linux application in Vitis. But when I choose the ip address of the board it complains that no Linux Tcf Agent is running? So how to check if the TCF is running in my target board?

Comment: `ps aux | grep tcf-agent`, or leave out the `aux` part if you are using busybox or similar minimal version of ps.

Comment: @skandigraun Thank you so much. You may write it as an answer please, so that I can accept it.